# Print Angular Expression

Tags: angularjs

I have a json object like this :

[image]

I store it in variable called data. If I use it in angular expression like this :
`{{data.2014-07-01}}` the result is error. (It should be print "`Potensial`")

How to access this type of expression in a proper way ?

Comment: Are you assigning it to `$scope.data`?

Comment: Try `{{ data['2014-07-01'] }}` instead

Comment: Thank you Adnan Umer, It works